# macOS / iPadOS: keyboard language doesn't change sometimes

Tags: macos, keyboard, siri, ipados, language

In 2021 I used iPad Pro 13' M1 with Magic Keyboard, language switch was set up for the Globe button. Sometimes language didn't change after the first press of the button, and it happened like 1 out of 5 times. Changing the language switch to neither <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, nor <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> didn't help.

Now I'm using MacBook Air M1, Ventura 13.5.2. Switching language with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, I quickly encountered the same issue.

I read about disabling/enabling Siri keyboard shortcut in Settings, but:

- there's only an option to change the keyboard shortcut, not disable it completely
- it really sounds like a quick fix instead of solving the problem once and for all
- disabling Siri completely and enabling it back didn't help
- shortcut change didn't help, it is set to "Mic" button, so no interference with <kbd>Cmd</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd>
- I also haven't found mentions of this bug on iPadOS with Magic Keyboard, though that's where I encountered this bug in the first place
- furthermore, sometimes when I switch between apps where inputs set for different languages when I start typing, the first 1-3+ letters are typed in a different language; i.e. in Firefox I'm on **A (ABC)**, press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to Telegram where it's **РУ (Russian)**, start typing **по-русски** and end up with **gj-русски**
- all the mentions of the exact same bug I found are about switching between **English and Russian** languages, which is my case as well; funny coincidence, or is it a Russian language bug?
- lastly, the MacBook Air 2017 High Sierra works perfectly fine even with the Siri shortcut set to <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, never encountered any of behaviour mentioned above

Given, that at least 2+ years have passed since this bug occurred, maybe somebody found a solution for both macOS and iPadOS? I can only check solutions on macOS, but it looks like a fix for one should help the other.

Appreciate any help. This is truly annoying, especially when your job is constantly messaging in different languages.

Update: Just updated to macOS Sonoma, the problem persists. At least with the new keyboard layout tooltip popup, it's easier to spot it.

Comment: One problem is that the user has almost no ability to fix such things in iOS because it is a closed system. You seem to have tried all the available remedies already.  MacOS is open and there are lots of things you can do which are just not possible in iOS, including 3rd party keyboards and keyboard switchers.

Comment: @TomGewecke thanks Tom, that's why I'm asking about a fix precisely, not for a workaround. I realise that on macOS I can solve it with 3rd party software, and probably will end up with it, but as I'm not the only one encountering this behavior, and it's not new, I was hoping somebody would have found a solution. I'm actually shocked to see so few search results, because as I said I bought a brand new iPad Pro, and there it was; I bought a brand new MacBook Air M1, and here it is again, so I thought the problem is common :(

Comment: If you happen to hate the new popup, as many do, see https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-250007827